# How to prevent changing wallpaper/Desktop background on fedora 14?

Tags: linux, fedora

Is there a way to avoid changing the wallpaper/Desktop background other the onces which come as default on fedora?

Answer (score 0):

[Sabayon](http://live.gnome.org/Sabayon) allows you to define various defaults for the GNOME environment and lock them down.